# Disabled Dayclick in fullcalendar for avoiding add events at same date and same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Thanks in advance ,

i have used full calendar in laravel 5 , all is working fine , but we need one validation for avoiding Add event for same date and same time.

For Example : if we added same event at 16 May , 2018 at 1:00 PM then same  event should not allowed , means need validation for not able to click , same date time.

I have already try some effort but not successed.

```
 $(".fc-widget-content").addClass("disabled-slot");
 $(".fc-minor .fc-widget-content").removeClass("disabled-slot");
 $(".fc-widget-content").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

dayclick event  is working . We need dayclick event disabled only if there slots (Event) exist.

My Code:

```
 $('#calendar'+cid).fullCalendar({
  events: json_events,
  height: 400,
  //events: [{"id":"14","title":"New Event","start":"2015-01-24T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":false}],
  utc: true,
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  selectOverlap: false, 
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, 
  defaultDate:d,
  slotDuration: '00:30:00' ,
  slotEventOverlap:false ,
```

Day click function :

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    // alert($(this).attr('class'));
    var calendarid = $(this).closest('div .outer-inner').attr('id'); 
    var eid = calendarid.split('_');
    var calendarName = $(this).closest('div .outer-inner').attr('employeeiname'); 
    var userid = {!! Session()->get('userID') !!}; 
    var usertype = "{!! Session()->get('UserType') !!}";  
    if(usertype=='GymOwner'){ 
    }else {
     if(eid[1]!=userid){  
         alert('Dont have permission.');
         revertFunc();
        return false; 
     }
    } 
    var employee_id =eid[1]+" - "+calendarName; //$("#trainerScheduling").val();
    var edata = employee_id.split('-'); 
    $(".privatetrainers").append('<option value="'+employee_id+'">'+edata[1]+'</option>');
    $('.privatetrainers').val(employee_id).trigger('change.select2');
    // var employee_id = $("#trainerScheduling").val();  
    $("#trainerScheduling").val(employee_id);
    var datatime = date.format(); 
    $("#dayclickvalue").val(datatime);
    var start = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS");
    var datetimestring = datatime.split("T"); 
    var options = {  year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }; 
    //  var start = new Date(datetimestring[0]);  
    //  var StartDate = datetimestring[0]; 
    var StartDate = moment(datetimestring[0]).format('MMMM D, YYYY'); 
    $("#session_date").val(StartDate);
    $("#meeting_date").val(StartDate);
    $("#muna_date").val(StartDate);
    //$("#muna_starttime").val(date.format("HH:mm:a")); 
    dynamicDatetime(date.format("hh:mm a"),'muna_starttime','muna_endtime'); 
    $("#muna_starttime").val(date.format("hh:mm a")); 
    // alert(date.format("h:mm a"));
    $("#starttimedropdownunv").val(date.format("hh:mm a"));
    //  $("#session_date").val(datetimestring[0]);
    // alert(date.format("HH:mm:a"));
    dynamicDatetime(date.format("hh:mm a"),'session_stime','session_etime'); 
    $("#session_stime").val(date.format("hh:mm a")); 
    // alert(date.format("h:mm a"));
    $("#starttimedropdown").val(date.format("hh:mm a")); 
    // $("#groupsession_date").val(datetimestring[0]);
    $("#groupsession_date").val(StartDate);
    dynamicDatetime(date.format("hh:mm a"),'groupsession_start','groupsession_end');
    $("#groupsession_starttimedropdown").val(date.format("hh:mm a"));  
    $("#groupsession_start").val(date.format("hh:mm a"));  
    //  $("#groupsession_start").val(date.format("HH:mm:a")); 
    // $("#meeting_starttime").val(date.format("HH:mm:a")); 
    dynamicDatetime(date.format("hh:mm a"),'meeting_starttime','meeting_endtime');
    $("#meeting_starttime").val(date.format("hh:mm a"));  
    $("#starttimedropdownmeeting").val(date.format("hh:mm a")); 
    $("#scheduleoptions").show();
    $(".schedule-first-step").hide();  

    },
```

Comment: `selectOverlap` sounds like something that would work: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap

Comment: thanks but still not working i have used like that please check and let me know.                      utc: true,
      header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      selectOverlap: function(event) {
        return event.rendering === 'background';
      },
      editable: true,
      droppable: true, 
      defaultDate:d,
      slotDuration: '00:30:00' ,
      slotEventOverlap:false ,

Comment: used selectOverlap  function but still not working , dayclick still working

Comment: Can you provide the full implementation of your calendar so that I don't have to guess how to solve this issue? You should edit your post rather than write code in the comment.

Comment: Even better if you can provide an example of your issue on https://jsfiddle.net/ ;-)

Comment: I  have edit my question please check Thanks

Comment: the edit doesn't show how you are adding events, or how the place to add the event is chosen, despite that apparently being the main problem. BTW in the comments you mention the use of "dayClick"...well then "selectoverlap" will have no effect if you are using "dayClick" as the means by which people select where to add the event. As per the recommended method in the documentation and demos you should be using the "select" callback for that task - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback/ . "selectOverlap:false" will then stop users from dragging the time period across an existing event.

Comment: I have added dayclick function as well in Question please check thanks

Comment: Did you understand what I said - you shouldn't be using dayClick for this purpose. If you use the "select" callback the user can drag and drop the event to the size they want, including specifying exact times (rather than having to type them in afterwards), and you can easily place constraints on that selection using things like "selectOverlap" etc.